# Do Enchantments on Weapons Scale with Sneak Attack Bonuses?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently I've built a character on Skyrim who focuses mainly on sneaking and bursting to death any enemy and I'm trying to max out my damage. I have been testing what I already have and with sneaking + 2 daggers I've one shot Sahloknir and Arngeir. My current build is Ebony Dagger + Blade of Woe x30 (x15 With Daggers Perk x2 for Jesters Gauntlets/Shrouded Gloves) which adds up to 1140 damage, but this lead to my question. Do enchantments like Absorb Health and Frost Damage scale with the x30 Sneak Attack, I'm just trying to max my damage. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. They don't. Tested it extensively myself. Would have been sweet tho. esp for life-steal ;)

but it would be overkill, so they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state that you are trying to max your damage with these weapons, there *is* a way to boost the damage of some weapon enchants.  It's just not with the Stealth skill tree.

Both of the Enchants you have asked about benefit from the [Destruction school](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction#Skill_Perks).

**Good news:** Frost related perks in that school will carry over to the Frost Damage Enchant.  Each level of `Augmented Frost` will add 25% to the enchant's damage.  The `Deep Freeze` perk should also add a Paralysis effect to victims under 20% health.  Oh, and if you're *really* intent on adding insult to injury that Paralysis effect should benefit from Alteration's `Stability`.  Additionally, both Enchants will eat less of the weapon's "soul food" if you have a high Destruction skill or if you equip any enchants that lower the mana cost of Destruction spells.  Also note that using these enchants will provide a slight trickle of Destruction XP.

FWIW:  Weapon enchants that *don't* use the Destruction school are dependent upon Illusion (Fear), Restoration (Turn Undead), Alteration (Paralyze), and Conjuration (Banish, Soul Trap & Fiery Soul Trap).

Details can be found [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchantments#Weapon_Effects).

Comment: You don't specifically say how this increases damage. I assume it's included in "frost related parks", but I don't really remember the destruction perk tree.

Comment: @DCShannon, I've edited my answer to include some of the details from the original link.